# Using AIC for to select models with equal number of parameters

Tags: regression, model, aic, linear

My research project is looking at various measurements that might predict wheat yield better than tiller (stem) counts. Some of my site-years have a measurement that requires a polynomial regression for best fit to yield. The nature of these measurements (counts, sensor readings, and percentages) create a huge difference in variation around the regression line- and I want a more "universal" statistic to compare them to against tiller counts.

So here is the question... can/should I use AIC to compare these models, most of which only have 1 parameter? Please note, that I am ONLY comparing within site-years, meaning the dependent variables are identical between each model being compared- the only difference is the independent variable of the model. Might adjusted R2 be a more appropriate statistic in this case?

I'm a statistics novice and really need help.... Thanks!

Comment: If you are using the regression for prediction the PRESS criterion would be a good choice. (measure how well they are prediciting using cross validation)

Answer (score 1):

You can use AIC in your situation.

However, if your aim is explicitly prediction, I'd say a measure of out-of-sample predictive accuracy would be more intuitive. Potentially including cross-validation. Just choose a good error measure or loss function, possibly [mse](/questions/tagged/mse), or something else. You could also look at the [diebold-mariano](/questions/tagged/diebold-mariano) test if you want to assess whether one model's predictions are significantly better than another one's.